# Silverlight Rss feeds and ClientAccessPolicy.xml

Tags: silverlight

We have a Silverlight application that requests some rss feeds from the client. Not from the server. All the other developers on our team are able to get all 5 of the rss feeds.

**Update to this issue. - I have cleared out all the rss feeds other than one. When this one rss feed is run through I still get a 404 on the clientaccesspolicy.xml file. I am the only one on our team that gets this. We have put in some exception handling around the Rss. We are getting this error.

Error reading feed http://sports.espn.go.com/espn/rss/ncf/news: [Security error.]

but fiddler still tells us that I am getting a 404 on the clientaccesspolicy file

I have also turned off all my firewalls.

There is clearly something different between my machine and the other machines..

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the clientaccesspolicy.xml exists on your machine.

Eg if your website application is at 
http://localhost:123/MySite/

The clientaccesspolicy.xml file needs to be in 
http://localhost:123/clientaccesspolicy.xml

Comment: thanks for the response. When I goto localhost:81/clientaccesspolicy.xml I get the file in the browser. And again to make my point possibly more clear. when I run the app and look at fiddler, sometimes that xml file is a 200 with some calls and other times(3x) i get a 404. i have 6 rss feeds that are being brought back. On the call to 3 of them I get 200's and the other 3 I get 404's. My team has no issue with any of them, they get 200's on all of them.

Comment: Sorry, I do not get a 200 on the ones that work. I get a 304.

Comment: I have cleared out all the Rss calls except one. Now even this one rss call is still giving me a 404 on the clientaccesspolicy.xml file. we have it in the root directory of our webserver. I am running this locally through the azure dev fabric.

Comment: @gevjen: 304 means Not Modified, which means the same as 200 in this case, the file was available in the client cache and was not modified, so a new download was not needed.